# Simple jQueryUI Dialog causes error with 1.9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I've previously used the following script and it worked perfectly.  I am now getting the following error:

```
Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'.
jquery-latest.js (line 507)
```

If you upgrade to jQueryUI 1.10.1, it no longer causes an error.  Normally, I would just let it go, upgrade, and not worry about it.  Problem with this one is that it worked in the past so why not now is driving me crazy?  I must be doing some silly thing different than previously, but I cannot see it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery UI Dialog</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <link type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#open").click(function(){$("#dialog").dialog('open');return false;});
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen    : false,
                    buttons: {
                        Ok: function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="open">Click</button>
        <div id="dialog" title="What ever"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it works with no problems in a newer version it must be a bug with the version you are using. I know it drives you crazy but that’s the life of a web developer. Stuff is constantly changing, sometimes even hour by hour!

Comment: Turns out it worked perfectly for me using jQuery 1.8.1, not using the latest version of jQuery!

Comment: That doesn’t matter. Bugs get introduced all the time and then fixed again in a later version, but your question mentioned that it worked correctly in jQuery 1.10.1 so I thought it was resolved by a bug fix.  There are many known issues in 1.9, that’s why 1.9.1 was released so shortly afterwards.

Comment: At least I am no longer going crazy!  I now know it didn't previously work under identical circumstances, and then mysteriously stop working.

Comment: Have you tried using the jQuery migrate plugin that they recommend using when upgrading to 1.9?

Comment: @j08691.  No.  Should I?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that i resolved by defining my button array outside of the dialog declaration.

```
var buttonArray = {};
buttonArray["Ok"]=function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" );}
```

Your options would become:

```
     modal: true,
     autoOpen: false,
     buttons: buttonArray
```